# Tmux autocomplete internal commands

Tags: tmux, autocomplete

Does anyone know a way to autocomplete tmux internal commands?

For example, inside tmux I type <kbd>bind-key</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> then type `ren...` and expect to get `rename-window` or similar by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tmux will autocomplete commands *when the entered string is unambiguous*.

In the example you provide, <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> could complete to either `rename` or `renumber`. In order to have the complete work, you would have to enter an additional character to remove the ambiguity: <kbd>a</kbd>.

Comment: Ok, thanks. IMHO it would be nicer to cycle ambiguous completions, so user can easily discover or recall the right commands.

Comment: @vlad Perhaps; it would probably introduce far more complexity than could be justified by the otherwise marginal utility.